# 'Configurable product' is losing currency format after choosing an option on dropdown menu

Tags: magento, drop-down-menu, currency, configurable-product

everyone.

The product's price is shown correctly, format and currency symbol. But when I choose an option from the dropdown, the price loses format and the symbol disappears. Does anyone here has seen this issue? How to fix it?

Example: http://coletivix.com/t-shirt.html

Magento version: 1.8.1.0

Comment: Share some code, just by viewing product page no one can advice you exactly what to do

Comment: I don't know which code to share. The files in /js/varien are the defaults. Configurable.php(app/code/core/mage/catalog/block/product/view/type/configuarble.php) also default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what was causing the problem.
The field (System > Configuration > General > Currency Setup

> Custom Currency Format) was filled and probably it resulted in a conflict some how.
>   Letting it empty solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Soem body was change in `confiriuable.js or Configurable.php(app/code/core/mage/catalog/block/product/view/type/configuarble.php)`
Please replace by default magento code

Comment: I replaced the files, refreshed everything, but the issue is not solved. Thank you anyway, Amit.